# Concurrency failure while updating identity user in asp.net core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

In my project I am using ASP.Net Core identity. I have an `ApplicationUser` class that has a list of `Education`.

```
public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser, IEntity
    {
        public ApplicationUser()
        {
            Educations = new List<Education>();
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }   

        public DateTime DateofBirth { get; set; }
        
        public virtual List<Education> Educations { get; set; }
    }
```

Education

```
public class Education:IEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid GUID { get; set; }
        public string Institution { get; set; }
        public string Degree { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to update User with Education list by UserManager.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateProfile(UpdateModel model)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                user.Name = model.UserDetails.Name;
                user.DateofBirth = model.UserDetails.DateofBirth;
                user.Educations = model.UserDetails.Educations;
                
                var userPassword = _userManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user, 
                                    user.PasswordHash, model.Password);

                if (userPassword != PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid Password.");
                    return Json("/Profile/Update");
                }
                else
                {
                    IdentityResult result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                }
            }
            return Json("/Profile/Index");
        }
```

Update Model

```
public class UpdateModel
    {
        public ApplicationUser UserDetails { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

While updating if I try to add a new Education object it gets concurrency failure. But an already existing education object updates properly.

Answer (score 0):

> While updating if I try to add a new Education object it gets concurrency failure. But an already existing education object updates properly.

Do you mean create and update in the same action?

You can try to set a if else to judge whether the database already has the user, then
create or edit the model,

like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateOrUpdateProfile(UpdateModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {              
            if (_context.ApplicationUsers.Any(x => x.Id == model.UserDetails.Id)) //judge
            {
                //Create...
            }
            else 
            {
                ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);           
                //Edit...
            }             
        }
        return Json("/Profile/Index");
    }
```